# Call a function every X second in a loop in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, settimeout, coinbase-api

My objective: Call a function every X second.

I'm using Coinbase pro API and get information of my wallet. There is a limit of API call per second. So I would like to call my function getWalletHistory() for each wallet every 5 seconds.

What I have: my function getWalletList() is called, then I wait for 5 seconds to call my function getWalletHistory().

What I want: Call my function getWalletHistory() for each wallet every 5 seconds.

```
var wallet_list = [];

getWalletList();

function getWalletList(){
    authedClient.getAccounts().then(wallet_list_response => {
        wallet_list_response.forEach(async wallet => {
            console.log("WALLET LIST:" + wallet.id);
            wallet_list.push(wallet);
        });
        console.log('**********END LOOP WALLET LIST');
        getWalletHistory(wallet_list);
    }).catch(error => {
        // handle the error
        console.log('ERROR getAccounts');
        //console.log(error);
    });
}

const getWalletHistory = async function(wallet_args){
    wallet_args.forEach(async wallet => {
        setTimeout(function(){
            authedClient.getAccountHistory(wallet.id).then(order_list => {
                console.log('*********response');
            }).catch(error => {
                // handle the error
                console.log('ERROR getAccountHistory');
                //console.log(error);
            });
        }, 5000);
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**
Following the comment of Erenn, I use SetInterval instead of SetTimeout:

```
var wallet_list = [];

getWalletList();

function getWalletList(){
    authedClient.getAccounts().then(wallet_list_response => {
        wallet_list_response.forEach(async wallet => {
            console.log("WALLET LIST:" + wallet.id);
            setInterval(() => getWalletHistory(wallet), 5000);
        });
        console.log('**********END LOOP WALLET LIST');
    }).catch(error => {
        // handle the error
        console.log('ERROR getAccounts');
        //console.log(error);
    });
}
const getWalletHistory = async function(wallet){
    console.log('*********getWalletHistory:' + wallet.currency);
    authedClient.getAccountHistory(wallet.id).then(order_list => {
        console.log('*********response order_list');
    }).catch(error => {
        // handle the error
        console.log('ERROR getAccountHistory');
        //console.log(error);
    });
}
```

What I have now: getAccountHistory() is called every 5 seconds for all the wallet in an infinite loop. I would like to call getAccountHistory() every 5 second for only 1 wallet at a time.

Comment: I think you want setInterval instead of setTimeout.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my post. I have a new error when I use setInterval

Comment: Because you're directly executing the function in the arguments, try with `() => getWalletHistory(wallet)`

Comment: Exactly, I didn't notice it !
The problem now is the function getWalletHistory() is called unlimited times. And every 5 seconds, I'm calling getWalletHistory() for all wallet, that I would like it's to call my function only for 1 wallet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could maintain a queue of list which setInterval could operate on every 5000 ms. Below updated snippet **check out `getWalletHistories` and its comments**

```js
var wallet_list = [];
getWalletList();

// responisble for maintaining queue (in the form of array) and setting interval
// Create a new reference of list, pop the item, calls getWalletHistory
// and once promise gets resolved, move the item back in the list (front of the array)
function getWalletHistories(walletList) {
  let interval;
  // clear interval counter if getWalletHistories called once again
  if (interval) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  const _list = [...walletList];
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    // pop wallet item from list for get wallet item history
    const wallet = _list.pop();
    getWalletHistory(wallet).then(() => {
      // push the popped wallet item back to the front of list
      _list.unshift(wallet);
    });
  }, 5000);
}

function getWalletList() {
  authedClient
    .getAccounts()
    .then((wallet_list_response) => {
      getWalletHistories(wallet_list_response);
      console.log("**********END LOOP WALLET LIST");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // handle the error
      console.log("ERROR getAccounts");
      //console.log(error);
    });
}

function getWalletHistories(walletList) {
  let interval;
  // clear interval counter if getWalletHistories called once again
  if (interval) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  const _list = [...walletList];
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    // pop wallet item from list for getting wallet item history
    const wallet = _list.pop();
    getWalletHistory(wallet).then(() => {
      // push the popped wallet item back to the front of list
      _list.unshift(wallet);
    });
  }, 5000);
}

const getWalletHistory = async function (wallet) {
  console.log("*********getWalletHistory:" + wallet.currency);
  // return the wallet history promise
  return authedClient
    .getAccountHistory(wallet.id)
    .then((order_list) => {
      console.log("*********response order_list", order_list);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // handle the error
      console.log("ERROR getAccountHistory");
      //console.log(error);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working well! 
I just modifyed the condition of the clearInterval   
if (interval) { clearInterval(interval); }
by: if(wallet.length === 0){ clearInterval(interval); }